# Spring ignores @Primary annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I've got a code that attempts to override a bean (*RedisIndexedSessionRepository*) defined in external dependency (spring-session-data-redis:2.2.0).

[Here's a full source of a class with bean definition](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java). Relevant part bellow:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class RedisHttpSessionConfiguration extends SpringHttpSessionConfiguration
        implements BeanClassLoaderAware, EmbeddedValueResolverAware, ImportAware {
    // ...

    @Bean
    public RedisIndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository() {
        // constructs and returns sessionRepository
    }

    // ...

    @EnableScheduling
    @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    class SessionCleanupConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {

        private final RedisIndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository;

        SessionCleanupConfiguration(RedisIndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository) {
            this.sessionRepository = sessionRepository;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

And here's a code trying to override the bean:

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@Configuration
public class CustomRedisHttpSessionConfiguration extends RedisHttpSessionConfiguration {
    // ...

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public RedisIndexedSessionRepository customSessionRepository() {
        RedisIndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository = super.sessionRepository();
        // custom config code
        return safeRepository;
    }

    // ...
}
```

When I attempt to start the application, an error is logged to the console:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in
>   org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$SessionCleanupConfiguration
>   required a single bean, but 2 were found:
>   // lists beans from both classes here 
>   Action:
>
> Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer
>   to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean
>   that should be consumed

Any ideas why **@Primary** is not taken into account here?

Comment: Because it isnt proxied. Just don't override the method, apparently you want to add some customizations to the repo, instead write a `BeanPostProcessor` which does this.

Answer (score 1):

Just add one property to your configuration:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

**EDIT**

or try something like that:

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@Configuration
public class CustomRedisHttpSessionConfiguration extends 
    RedisHttpSessionConfiguration implements BeanPostProcessor {
    // ...

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean.getClass() == RedisIndexedSessionRepository.class) {
            RedisIndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository = (RedisIndexedSessionRepository) bean;
            // custom config code
        }
        return bean;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I already have that property set. Without it, application would fail earlier.


The problem is that overridden bean is not recognized as primary and dependency injection fails bacause there are two beans of the same class.